# Cycle rendering alpha texture problem，the transparency effect to be wrong

Tags: cycles-render-engine

#### You can see the difference between eyebrows and eyelashes,The eyebrows are very close to the skin causing the transparency effect to be wrong

#### How can this be solved?

[image]

#### This is the skin shader

[image]

#### This is the eyebrows shader

> The eyebrows are separate grids

[image]

### [This is demo](https://github.com/ZeronoFreya/Gallery/raw/master/ball.zip)

Comment: Are the eyebrows a patch (separate mesh/object)? And are they particles or just a texture? How does the shader of the eyebrows look like?

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the reply, I added the content of the eyebrows, it is a separate grid

Comment: Your shader looks ok. Have you tried to disconnect the *Alpha* slot of the *Principled BSDF *and set it to 0? Then the eyebrow should be totally invisible. How have you placed the eyebrow grid? I've just tried [this eyebrows image](https://www.pngkey.com/detail/u2q8o0i1t4r5y3o0_eyebrows-images-pluspng-world-eyebrow-png/), shrinkwrapped it with a tiny offset to avoid Z-fighting. It works as expected in Cycles (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBnwG.jpg) and Eevee (needs to set the Blend Mode in materials settings to Alpha Blend or Alpha Hashed). The 1st Color Ramp & RGBtoBW node are onlyfor testing.

Comment: @Blunder Alpha is 0 will also be displayed, I made a demo, the link is at the end of the article

Comment: Thank you for the demo. That helped to track down the problem. (It's the AO node.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your demo exposed the culprit. It is the [Ambient Occlusion](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/shader_nodes/input/ao.html) node of your skin shader. This is the one I suspected the least.

I usually bake the AO to a texture because it's an expensive node and increases render time significantly. That's the reason I had never run into this problem before.

[image: example]
<sup>In the demo, a blue plane with a transparent gradient is placed over the sphere.</sup>

The AO node doesn't know about transparency and just does its job and mixes a shadow color into the base color where the eyebrow patch is placed over the body mesh. This shadow then becomes visible through transparency.

To avoid this you can check the `[X]` *Only Local* option in the node. This ignores all other objects when the AO is calculated. Or bake the AO to a texture and replace the AO node with the baked texture.